# Static node distance tikz matrix of math nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw the following diagram in tikz,

```
    \documentclass[b5paper,10pt,twoside]{book}
    \usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1]{geometry}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,through,backgrounds,matrix,decorations.pathmorphing}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes, row sep=2em, column sep=2em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex]
    {X        & \,        & Z         & \,        & Z/Y      & \,       & (Y/X)[1]   \\
    \,        & Y         & \,        & Z/X       & \,       & Y[1]     &         \,         \\
    \,        & \,        & Y/X       & \,        & X[1]     & \,       &         \,         \\};
    \path[->,font=\scriptsize]
    %top arrows
    (m-1-1) edge[bend left =45] node[above] {$g\circ f    $} (m-1-3)
    (m-1-3) edge[bend left =45] node[above] {$            $} (m-1-5)
    (m-1-5) edge[bend left =45] node[above] {$\theta      $} (m-1-7)
    %lower edge border arrows
    (m-1-1) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-2-2)
    (m-2-2) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-3-3)
    (m-3-3) edge[bend right=45] node[below] {$            $} (m-3-5)
    (m-3-5) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-2-6)
    (m-2-6) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-1-7)

    %completing second dt
    (m-2-2) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-1-3)
    (m-1-5) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-2-6)
    ;
    \path[dashed,->,font=\scriptsize]
    (m-1-3) edge                node[above] {$            $} (m-2-4)
    (m-2-4) edge                node[above] {$            $} (m-3-5)

    (m-3-3) edge                node[above] {$            $} (m-2-4)
    (m-2-4) edge                node[above] {$            $} (m-1-5)
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

    \end{document}
```

But it seems like, since the text in the right nodes are longer than the text in the left nodes that, the gadgets "pizza slices" on the left are smaller than the gadgets on the right. 
[image]

Does anyone know how to force the distances between the nodes to be equal, that might work in this particular diagram. For some other diagrams in the same document I guess that I cannot change the premable. Cheers!

Comment: Use the `\node (Z) [right=0.3cm of X]` with the tikz library 'positioning`. you can fix the alignment of a node using `align=center`.

Comment: Please, look at updated answer. It's easier than original one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Sometimes it's worth to better look at `pgfmanual` before answering a question. My previous answer was correct but rereading "Matrices and Alignment" section I've found `between origins` option which better solves nunatak's problem.

> `/tikz/column sep=<spacing list>`
>
> This option sets a default space that is added between every two columns. [...]
>
> More generally, the  may contain a whole list of numbers, separated by commas, and occurrences of the two key words `between origins` and `between borders`. [...] However, if the last occurs is `between origins`, then the following happens: The distance between the columns is adjusted such that the difference between the origins of all the cells in the first column (remember that they all lie on straight line) and the origins of all the cells in the second column is exactly the given distance.
>
> The `between origins` option can only be used for columns mentioned in the first row, that is, you cannot specify this option for columns introduced only in later rows.

So, just changing `column sep=3em` with `column sep={3em, betweens origins}` in `matrix` options, the adjustment problem is solved.

[image]

**Original answer**

A `matrix` helps you to easily place nodes but `row` and `column` dimensions are computed according nodes text. If you want to avoid *missplacements* due to differences in nodes sizes, you can use `on grid` with certain `node distance` to easily position nodes according their centers instead of their borders.

Next code shows how to solve your problem. I've kept node's names to avoid changing `edge` commands. I've also drawn a `grid` to show how nodes are placed.

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[black!30] (0,0) grid [xstep=1.5cm, ystep=1.5cm] (9,-3.5);
\begin{scope}[on grid, node distance=3cm]
\node (m-1-1) at (0,0) {$X$};
\node[right=of m-1-1] (m-1-3) {$Z$};
\node[right=of m-1-3] (m-1-5) {$Z/Y$};
\node[right=of m-1-5] (m-1-7) {$(Y/X)[1]$};

\node[below right= 1.5cm and 1.5cm of m-1-1] (m-2-2) {$Y$};
\node[right=of m-2-2] (m-2-4) {$Z/X$};
\node[right=of m-2-4] (m-2-6) {$Y[1]$};

\node[below right= 1.5cm and 1.5cm of m-2-2] (m-3-3) {$Y/X$};
\node[right=of m-3-3] (m-3-5) {$X[1]$};
\end{scope}

    \path[->,font=\scriptsize]
%top arrows
(m-1-1) edge[bend left =45] node[above] {$g\circ f    $} (m-1-3)
(m-1-3) edge[bend left =45] node[above] {$            $} (m-1-5)
(m-1-5) edge[bend left =45] node[above] {$\theta      $} (m-1-7)
%lower edge border arrows
(m-1-1) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-2-2)
(m-2-2) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-3-3)
(m-3-3) edge[bend right=45] node[below] {$            $} (m-3-5)
(m-3-5) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-2-6)
(m-2-6) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-1-7)

%completing second dt
(m-2-2) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-1-3)
(m-1-5) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-2-6)
;
\path[dashed,->,font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-3) edge                node[above] {$            $} (m-2-4)
(m-2-4) edge                node[above] {$            $} (m-3-5)

(m-3-3) edge                node[above] {$            $} (m-2-4)
(m-2-4) edge                node[above] {$            $} (m-1-5)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One ugly way will be to use the corners of `node`s to connect like:

```
(m-1-1.north east) edge[bend left =45] node[above] {$g\circ f    $} (m-1-3.north west)
```

with some `minimum width` defined (I kept it as the width of `$(Y/X)$`. you can adjust this.)

```
\documentclass[b5paper,10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[hmarginratio=1:1]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,through,backgrounds,matrix,decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix(m)[matrix of math nodes, row sep=2em, column sep=2em, text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex,minimum width=\widthof{$(Y/X)$}]
{X        & \,        & Z         & \,        & Z/Y      & \,       & (Y/X)[1]   \\
\,        & Y         & \,        & Z/X       & \,       & Y[1]     &         \,         \\
\,        & \,        & Y/X       & \,        & X[1]     & \,       &         \,         \\};
\path[->,font=\scriptsize]
%top arrows
(m-1-1.north east) edge[bend left =45] node[above] {$g\circ f    $} (m-1-3.north west)
(m-1-3.north east) edge[bend left =45] node[above] {$            $} (m-1-5.north west)
(m-1-5.north east) edge[bend left =45] node[above] {$\theta      $} (m-1-7.north west)
%lower edge border arrows
(m-1-1.south east) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-2-2.north west)
(m-2-2.south east) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-3-3.north west)
(m-3-3.south east) edge[bend right=45] node[below] {$            $} (m-3-5.south west)
(m-3-5.north east) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-2-6.south west)
(m-2-6.north east) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-1-7.south west)

%completing second dt
(m-2-2.north east) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-1-3.south west)
(m-1-5.south east) edge                node[below] {$            $} (m-2-6.north west)
;
\path[dashed,->,font=\scriptsize]
(m-1-3.south east) edge                node[above] {$            $} (m-2-4.north west)
(m-2-4.south east) edge                node[above] {$            $} (m-3-5.north west)

(m-3-3.north east) edge                node[above] {$            $} (m-2-4.south west)
(m-2-4.north east) edge                node[above] {$            $} (m-1-5.south west)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image].